# Laravel 5 Operation timed out

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, dedicated-server

laravel 5 giving me "Operation timed out"  after 30 second on hostgator dedicated server.

But I change the max time to 3600 second and  Its working without error on my localhost

my code is

```
$total = '';
for ($i=0;$i<60;$i++){
    $total .=  $i;
    sleep(1);
}
echo $total;
```

links  http://oemsys.net/test2

---

No I use dedicated server 
so I think i must add in my codes only

```
safe mode = off
memory_limit = 256M  
max_execution_time = 3600  
max_input_time = 60  
post_max_size = 64M  
upload_max_filesize = 64M  
enable_dl = on
```

Comment: It ran without a problem for me, you could check `max_execution_time` on your server.

Answer (score 1):

because its looping 60 times it need 60secs,

are you shared hosting hostgator? if yes, currently hostgator have some PHP settings that cannot be changed..

```
safe mode = Off (cannot adjust)
memory_limit = 256M (MAXIMUM)
max_execution_time = 30 (MAXIMUM in seconds)
max_input_time = 60 (MAXIMUM in seconds)
post_max_size = 64M (MAXIMUM)
upload_max_filesize = 64M (MAXIMUM)
enable_dl = Off (cannot adjust)
```

source : http://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-policies/php-settings-that-cannot-be-changed

my suggestions why using sleep? or try upgrade to VPS or other shared hosting can edit your PHP.ini